# I wrote a simple VBA to change the word page setup. it is working well, suddenly it beginto popup a window shows as below

Tags: vba, ms-word, page-setup

```vb
Sub Pagesetup()

    With ActiveDocument.Pagesetup
        .PaperSize = wdPaperA4
        .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Error message pop up

[image: 1]

Add the one drive path in the trust list

Comment: Why not simply use a Word document with these settings? What does "Add the one drive path in the trust list" mean in this context? Is that part of an error message?

Comment: THE DOCM FILE IS SAVED IN ONE DRIVE

Comment: Move the file to a trusted location on your computer. If it needs to be on OneDrive as well, put it in a folder on your computer, listed as a Trusted Location, that is synced to OneDrive. The macro should really be not in a .docm but a .dotm file that is loaded as a global template. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global Documents are not a good place to store general use macros. (I should have said "template" before as well.)